# Typedef of function in class with templates: is not a type

Tags: c++, c++14

I have class WtVector which contains an array[Dimension] and I don't want to access to its elements directly, so I came up with an idea to make mapper function type, so if I needed to have say 5th variable, I go like mapper(5) but not vector.el[4]

```
template <typename Space, int Dim>
struct WtVector {
    Space el[Dim] = {};

    typedef Space (*Mapper)(int);

    Mapper getMapper();
 };
```

But whenever I put WtVector<Space, Dim>::Mapper as type the compiler shouts that it's not a type

```
template <typename Space, int Dim>
struct WtVectorOps {
    ... some other stuff ...

    static Space sqrMagnitue(WtVector<Space, Dim>::Mapper vec);
};
```

Error:

```
error: ‘WtVector<Space, Dim>::Mapper’ is not a type
static Space sqrMagnitue(WtVector<Space, Dim>::Mapper vec);
                                               ^
```

Is it possible to have such typedef in class and if not what is the best alternative solution? If there exists easier solution than creating subclass and defining operator()

Comment: Try `typename WtVector<Space, Dim>::Mapper`

Comment: Tried typedef Space (WtVector<Space, Dim>::*Mapper)(int); and it didn't work

Comment: The suggestion was: try `static Space sqrMagnitue(typename WtVector<Space, Dim>::Mapper vec);`

Comment: @Arthur changing the typedef won't solve the problem. If you had a recent compiler, it would warn you that you need `typename` in front of a dependent type.

Comment: I think it solved the problem. Thank you guys!